# tableview loading invisible rows as well , cellforrowat index path getting celled for hidden rows

Tags: swift, uitableview

Tableview loading invisible rows as well , `cellForRowAtIndexPath` getting celled for hidden rows

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return ordersArray.count;
 }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       let selectedOrder = ordersArray[indexPath.section]

        return CGFloat(180 + (30 * selectedOrder.lineItems().count ));
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2;
       }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            let deliveryShipChargesCustomCell = 
 tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DeliveryShipChargesCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! DeliveryShipChargesCustomCell


            return deliveryShipChargesCustomCell;
        }
        else
       {
            let orderCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrdersCustomCell" , for: indexPath) as! OrdersCustomCell

            return orderCustomCell;
        }

    }
```

problem with this code snippet is that it gets load row that are not even visible for example if order array count is `10`. and there are two rows in each section , initially `tableview (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: IndexPath)`  gets called for `20` times.

Any thoughts?

Comment: it call 20 times because numberOfRowsInSection method you return 2, Make it 1

Comment: I have to add 2 rows for each section , that is I am returning 2 , but my cell height is 400 almost , keeping that in view I should only get first section, cellforRow should not get called for second section right? but it gets called 10*2 = 20 times

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have timer in each tableview custom cell, when this cell loads initially (when it is not visible yet) It schedules a timer at the time , and when I scroll it to view the cell it schedules a timer again. so timers gets invoked twice for single cell

Comment: How do you set frame/constraints for the tableview?

Comment: from storyboard, from superview 0 , left 0 , right 0, botttom aligned with superview 0